# How can I print line number of error with pkg/errors in go?

Tags: go

I was able to print the line number of error with [juju/errors](https://github.com/juju/errors), but not sure how to do the same with [pkg/errors](https://github.com/pkg/errors).

```
package main

import (
    jerrors "github.com/juju/errors"
    perrors "github.com/pkg/errors"

    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func jerror() error {
    //throw an error....
    _, err := ioutil.ReadDir("r")
    if err != nil {
        return jerrors.Trace(err)
    }
    return nil
}

func perror() error {
    //throw an error....
    _, err := ioutil.ReadDir("r")
    if err != nil {
        return perrors.Cause(err)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    jerr := jerror()
    if jerr != nil {
        log.Println(jerrors.ErrorStack(jerr))
    }

    log.Println("-------------------------")

    perr := perror()
    if perr != nil {
        log.Println(perrors.WithStack(perr))
    }
}
```

**Prints out :**

```
2020/08/26 00:19:48 open r: no such file or directory
go-mock-json-api/main.go:15: 
2020/08/26 00:19:48 -------------------------
2020/08/26 00:19:48 open r: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error from `pkg/errors` will not print the stack when using the default `String()` method, **print it with `"%+v"` instead**.

This is explained in the [formatted printing of errors](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors#hdr-Formatted_printing_of_errors) section of the docs:

> All error values returned from this package implement fmt.Formatter and can be formatted by the fmt package. The following verbs are supported:
>
> ```
> %s    print the error. If the error has a Cause it will be
>       printed recursively.
> %v    see %s
> %+v   extended format. Each Frame of the error's StackTrace will
>       be printed in detail.
> ```

The docs for [WithStack](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors#WithStack) has examples showing the different behaviors:

```golang
cause := errors.New("whoops")
err := errors.WithStack(cause)
fmt.Println(err)

// Output:
// whoops

fmt.Printf("%+v", err)

// Output:
// whoops
// github.com/pkg/errors_test.ExampleWithStack_printf
//         /home/fabstu/go/src/github.com/pkg/errors/example_test.go:55
// testing.runExample
// ...
```

Note that if you directly use `errors.New`, you don't need to use `WithStack`, [errors.New](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors#New) already does it for you as seen in this [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/BOnvGpCA58i):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

func main() {
    err := errors.New("whoops")
    fmt.Printf("String: %s\n", err)
    fmt.Printf("Verbose: %+v\n", err)

}
```

Outputs:

```
String: whoops
Verbose: whoops
main.main
    /tmp/sandbox878560423/prog.go:10
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
```